# Related to successive interference cancellation?

Tags: digital-communications, fading-channel, interference

I am trying to understand the following query: " Is it necessary to do channel estimation to perform successive interference cancellation at the receiver operating over fading channel"

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Successive cancellation is a concept used in many applications especially in communication theory. (such as non-orthogonal multiple access (NOMA), V-BLAST, Polar codes, in-band full-duplex communication). You say "successive cancellation", but if you tell the application domain, I will be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply....My application domain is Backscatter Communication....

Comment: Can someone answer my query....